# Denormalize a array of objects into a denormalized array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a way to denormalize an array of objects in JavaScript to obtain a set of arrays. I need that structure for a table (denormalized set of data).

So, given the input:

```
var data = [
    { v1: 1, v2: [ { a: 1 }, { a: 2 } ] },
    { v1: 2, v2: [ { a: 3 }, { a: 4 } ], v3: 5 },
];
```

I need a structure like

```
var data2 = [
    { v1: 1, v2_a: 1 },
    { v1: 1, v2_a: 2 },
    { v1: 2, v2_a: 3, v3: 5 },
    { v1: 2, v2_a: 4, v3: 5 }
];
```

Recursive way.

My first attempt is to do a full scan search in depth adding the properties in a temporal variable:

```
var result = [];
function aArray(data) {
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        var temp = {};
        for(var prop in data[i]){
            var val = data[i][prop];
            if( Object.prototype.toString.call( val ) === '[object Array]' ) {
                aArray(val);
            }else{
                temp[prop] = val;
            }
        }
        result.push(temp);
    }
}
```

But something doesn't work as expected

Comment: Do you want to do this expansion generically for any property that contains an array and does it need to work for arrays nested inside of arrays?  Or just the `v2` property at the top level?  Does it need to work for objects nested inside of objects so the sub-objects get expanded within their own world too?

Comment: The thing that doesn't work as expected is that you have 4 objects in your desired output array and only 2 are being created from the input array.

Comment: Dude. I was trying but I have no more time to finish it.. you may try to finish yourself. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nPMcF/). Sorry.. =/

Comment: Sorry. Generic way. Doesn't mather the properties and the depth level and must work in a recursive way.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution

```
var data = [
    { v1: 1, v2: [ { a: 1 }, { a: 2 } ] },
    { v1: 2, v2: [ { a: 3 }, { a: 4 } ], v3: 5 },
];

function is_a(a){
  return (typeof a == "object") && (a instanceof Array);
}
function extend(a, b){
  for(var i in b){
    a[i] = b[i];
  }
  return a;
}
```

Now main logic here:

```
var p = data.map(function(item){

  var output = {};
  var list   = [];

  for(var i in item){
    if(is_a(item[i])){
      for(var j = 0; j < item[i].length; j++){
        for(var z in item[i][j]){
          var k = {}; k[i + "_" + z] = item[i][j][z];
          list.push(k);
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      output[i] = item[i];
    }
  }    

  for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    list[i] = extend(list[i], output);
  }

  console.log(list);

});
```

Output:
First

0: Object
v1: 1
v2_a: 1

1: Object
v1: 1
v2_a: 2

Second

0: Object
v1: 2
v2_a: 3
v3: 5

1: Object
v1: 2
v2_a: 4
v3: 5

Try [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hJcmE/2/)

Comment: Recursive way. Based on your comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zFvZB/
But still doesn't work...